# Custom headers set ignored in Open/Save dialogs for a single folder under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In all my Windows systems I am using custom header configuration on My Computer / Computer / This PC for all types of customisations, i.e. *General items*, *Documents*, *Pictures*, *Music* and *Videos*:

[image]

My custom sets are respected by Windows 10 everywhere, **except for `C:\Trash` folder** (my private folder, not related (?) in any way to system trash) when its contents are browsed in Open or Save dialog in any application.

### Any folder -- This PC / Computer / Windows Explorer (correct!):

[image]

### Any folder -- This PC / Computer / Windows Explorer (correct!):

[image]

### Any folder -- Open / Save dialog (correct!):

[image]

### `C:\Trash` folder -- Open / Save dialog (**incorrect**!):

[image]

### `Desktop` folder -- Open / Save dialog (**incorrect**!):

[image]

I can (hardly) understand that Windows 10 ignores my custom columns settings when browsing *Desktop* folder, *user folder* or any other system-like folder. But, why the hell it does the same for a regular folder on my C:\ disk?

What I managed to figure out so far is:

- after renaming `C:\Trash` into `C:\Trash1` or `C:\Bugabuga` custom columns sets are correct,
- after renaming it bach to `C:\Trash` they are again incorrect,
- after deleting `C:\Trash` and recreating it they are again incorrect.

It seems that `C:\Trash` is treated by Windows 10 like other system-like folders.  And for all these folders custom columns sets are ignored. Is this a bug or hidden feature in Windows?

Is there any workaround (other that renaming `C:\Trash` to something else permanently?

Comment: @harrymc Question completely reedited to provide new facts and to address recent findings. Removing previous comment as it is now out-dated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not caused by some installed application, here is how to apply one
folder's setting to all folders :

- View another folder with which the display is correct
- Under View, click Options
- In the View tab, click Apply to Folders

Comment: As it was explained in the previous version of my question, this solution doesn't work. Both this solution and manually adjusting columns settings are for this single folder (and all other system-like folders?) respected by Windows 10 only until next reset. This solution is also not working because it changes how _This PC_ / Windows Explorer shows folder contents. And -- as said in my question -- there are no problems with this. The only problem is when displaying this folder contents in Open or Save dialogs in Windows 10.

Comment: Does this arrive when booting in Safe mode?